# How to freeze position for a time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

sorry for my English, I'm new in C#. I created a script in which I teleport the ball, but when the ball is teleported, it retains its speed. How can I stop the ball for a while after teleporting. I tried to do it using bool "isTeleported" and
`if (isTeleported == true){rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition;}`
It didn't work. . Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: Have a look at : [RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition.html)

Comment: I have seen this article https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition.html. but I need to do it automatically when teleporting and for a some time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html

You could just set your rigidbody.velocity to a vector3.zero.

```
rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
```